# AWS - scheduling Instance Type change possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

It is possible to schedule Instance Stop, Start, creating an image but I can't figure out how to change instance type?

Idea behind is to change the type for a cheaper instance during off peak(night time) and move back to the regular one in the morning. LoadBalancing won't work here.
The flow would look like:

1) Stop Instance
2) Create AMI
3) Change instance type
4) Start Instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use ModifyInstanceAttribute? It can be applied to stopped instances and allows you to change the instance type. You can do it from inside a Lambda by using the Node.js SDK (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#modifyInstanceAttribute-property)